# troubleshooting battery performance (toshiba satellite)

Tags: battery-life, battery

I replaced my old rankling battery with a new one, but something odd is happening, the battery reaches some level (say 30) and then jump straightly to 7% with a dialog box that normally appears when battery is in critical level.
the wear level is already 2.3, but the battery is 1 days old.
I checked the battery charging using 'powercfg energy' command, approximately 10000 mWh is lost.
the questing is, is it battery problem, does the battery need collaboration, or is it defected ? (its class A bought it for 70$).
help please.

Comment: When you say "first class", do you mean it's an officially branded battery bought from the manufacturer (Toshiba)?

Comment: not toshiba brand, but class A electronic ware, its not the issue, i just want to know if its the battery that is defected, or that my pc need maintenance.

Comment: The FCC electronics class has nothing to do with quality, rather the type of product it is and how it's permitted to interact with other electronics. I would be weary about 3rd-party batteries. They are cheap for a reason, and may not be put through as rigorous quality control as official batteries, may not be the same capacity, and may be more likely to explode.

Comment: just for reference:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Solutions-to-common-battery-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a defective battery....or the unnamed manufacturer's battery is not compatible with your system.

Generally, to avoid problems like this, I try to stick with the manufacturers' battery unless I am absolutely sure that the brand-X manufacturer will work properly.

Comment: just to be sure, does the charger have anything to do with this issue or its pure battery stuf

Comment: Most of the time when I have seen 3rd party batteries purchased for notebooks, there have almost always been problems.  It is definitely recommended to purchase OEM batteries whenever possible.  The extra money you're spending, will save you in headaches, shipping costs, and downright aggravation.

Comment: @sarepta If you're still using the official Toshiba charger that came with the laptop, then it's just the battery.